# $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and bijective: Prove: $g$ is strictly monotonous

Tags: analysis, functions

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and bijective function. Prove: $g$ is strictly monotonous.

I dont know where to start. Maybe i need to find an interval and show it for a small piece in $\mathbb{R}$?
Appreciate any help :-)

Comment: Start thinking about this geometrially, if you have the graph of a function, how does the graph of its inverse (if exist) look?

Comment: ok. the function is continuous. That means that it does not have a "cut" in the middle if i would ("could") draw it. It is bijective. That means every value from my set has a counterpart in the opposite set. Correct?

Comment: That is correct. I'd suggest you to take a few simple examples and draw their graphs as well as their inverse graphs, examples such as $3x+1, x^3, e^x$.

Comment: ok, i entered all values to wolfram. It just mirrored from the diagonal. I don not know what this have to do with the inverse but i think i understand now that if a function is continuous then the inverse is too. How can this help me? I think i stillt doesnt understand something

Comment: So now you know that the graph of the inverse (again, if the inverse exists) is the graph of the original function mirrored from the diagonal. This actually gives you a geometric characterization of biyective functions: a function is biyective iff the graph mirrored form the diagonal is the graph of a function (notice that this is not always the case, for example with $f(x)=x^2$), that is, it doesn't have two points on the same vertical. Now, how does this relate to the original map being strictly increasing?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $g$ does not have to be monotone, i.e. there exist $x_1<x_2<x_3$ with $g(x_1),g(x_3)<g(x_2)$ or with $g(x_1),g(x_3)>g(x_2).$ Let's have a look at the first case (the second is dealt with in the same way):

By the intermediate value theorem $[g(x_1),g(x_2)]\subset g([x_1,x_2]) $ and also $[g(x_3),g(x_2)]\subset g([x_2,x_3]) $. So there exist $t\in (x_1,x_2)$ and $t'\in (x_2,x_3)$ with $g(t)=M=g(t')$, where $M$ is some number with $\max\{g(x_1),g(x_3)\}<M<g(x_2).$ This however contradicts that $g$ is bijective.